# How to define size of an array by passing a variable in [] in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

My code is given below. I want to declare an array of size `n`.

```
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("myfile.b", "rb");
if(fp==NULL){ fputs("file error", stderr); exit(1); }
int* a;
fread(a, 0x1, 0x4, fp);
int n=*a;
int array[n];  // here is an error
```

How can I declare an array of size `n` in this code?

Comment: Why are you using C code in C++? C++ have a [very nice input/output library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io).

Comment: An example of perfectly valid C code does not work in C++...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg "very" nice is a matter of taste. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a declaration of a [variable-length array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and it's not in C++ yet.

Instead I suggest you use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead:

```
std::vector<int> array(n);
```

---

You also have other problems, like declaring a pointer but not initializing it, and then using that pointer. When you declare a local variable (like `a`) then its initial value is *undefined*, so using that pointer (except to assign to it) leads to *undefined behavior*. In this case what will probably happen is that your program will crash.

Comment: don't forget `#include <vector>`

Answer (score 0):

```
int *array = (int*)malloc( n * sizeof(int) );
//..
//your code
//..
//..
free(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare an array of variable size in C++, but you can allocate memory once you know how much you need:

int* a = new int[n];

//do something with your array...

//after you are done:

delete [] a;

Answer (score 0):

Since your code looks more like C...

```
FILE *fp = fopen("myfile.b", "rb");

if(fp==NULL)
{ 
  fputs("file error", stderr); 
  exit(1); 
}

//fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_END ); // position at end
//long filesize = ftell(fp);// get size of file
//fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_SET ); // pos at start

int numberOfInts = 0;
fread(&numberOfInts, 1, 4, fp); // you read 4 bytes sizeof(int)=4?
int* array = malloc( numberOfInts*sizeof(int) );
```

Comment: int* array = malloc( numberOfInts*sizeof(int) ); in this line there occure an error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'int *'

Comment: @azam42: That's the error you get when compiling as C++. This answer is valid C. That said, I'd suggest `int array[numberOfInts]` if you use C.

Comment: @MSalters: it is working in c++ by specifying the type of array from void to int like this                                                      int* array = (int *)malloc( numberOfInts*sizeof(int) );

Comment: when you compile that code with a C++ compiler then it is not valid to write just p = malloc(...) in C it is valid and the recommended way to do it. That is why you need the cast - I assumed a C compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Array only accept const object or expressions, the value can be decided by the compiler during compiling, vector from c++ is more suitable from this case, otherwise we need to dynamically allocate memory for it.